# what does curl do when just indicating a URL?

Tags: curl

My apologies for the extremely simple question
I have seen `curl` used to upload and download a file to a server but I cannot understand what does curl does in something like this

```
curl -f --user user1:xxxx ftp://the.server//the/path/
```

What is the result of this?

Reading pages like [this one](https://flaviocopes.com/http-curl/) it says

> When you perform a request, curl will return the body of the response:
>
> `curl https://flaviocopes.com/`

but I don't understand what that does mean. Return "the body of the response"? What is the "body of the response"??

Answer (score 0):

For a simple request like this: `curl https://flaviocopes.com/`, protocol `HTTP/HTTPS`, without any options, `curl` send a `GET /` request. You can see it with `--verbose` option:

```
...
> GET / HTTP/2
...
```

The (by default unvisible) response headers are:

```
< HTTP/2 200 
< date: Mon, 14 Nov 2022 12:23:29 GMT
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< access-control-allow-origin: *
...
```

200 code said it's ok

The body is simply, the HTML content of the `/` server page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
...
```

In your navigator, your can see the same source of the page by context menu or navigator tools menu.

Don't hesitate to use `--verbose` option to see all requests and responses between client and server. It works for all protocols

Comment: I realized I am calling curl with a ftp address... does that change anything?

Comment: Yes! It's the protocol! HTTP protocol is used for the Web and FTP is a (old) protocol to exchange files. By default the TCP port for HTTP is 80, for HTTPS is 443 and FTP are 20 & 21

Comment: so what do I get if curl is called on a ftp address as above?

Comment: By default, curl sent a listing command. See some examples: https://www.filestash.app/ftp-with-curl.html